# Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file: C:\Users\Miki\.android\avd\Pixel_XL_API_26.avd/userdata.img

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I've got a issue to my Android studio Emulator, when I always go to run my app the app get stopped, even if there isn't mistakes in the code, the debugging looks fine but when the emulator goes on.

**Error:**

```
`Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file: C:\Users\Miki\.android\avd\Pixel_XL_API_26.avd/userdata.img.`
```

May anyone let me know what can be the problem? I will appreciate it. I hope I have been clear, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### There are two requirements:

- The first possibility is not enough RAM space.
- The second possibility is using emulator onboard graphics.

### Here's what you can do:

1. Use lower API for system image. (For example: KitKat)
2. For the emulator, edit the settings for use the external graphics
   card
3. For the emulator, edit the settings for lower RAM and lower
   screen resolution.
4. Add new RAM to your computer.